# Size Classes for iPhone 6s and iPhone 6s Plus

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, size-classes

As in apple documentation [Apple Size Classes Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html) size classes defined for all iPhone and iPad families but here didn't mention for iPhone 6S and iPhone 6S Plus. So what i should set size classes for iPhone 6S and iPhone 6S Plus to get required user interface.

Answer (score 2):

The size classes are the same with the non-s models. That means, for iPhone 6s it is same with iPhone 6, and for iPhone 6s+ it is same with iPhone 6+.